# Fastest way to clear form input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for the fastest way to clear form input fields on a page reload. After reading previous posts I found there are a number of methods to do this including JavaScript and jQuery methods:

First method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input1").val('');
});
```

Another method:

```
$("#form").trigger('reset');
```

I just would like to know what is the fastest way to clear form input fields on a browser page reload using any method?

Comment: _"looking for the fastest way to clear form input fields on a page reload"_ Form fields not cleared  ,element values persisting at page reload ?

Comment: Have you tried using [`autocomplete="off"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete)?

Comment: Do you mean navigating 'back' in the browser rather than refreshing the page as that is usually when values are remembered?  Why do you want the fastest way, are you trying to avoid flicker of old values, or have lots of fields and performance is an issue, etc?

Comment: Hello yes I have tried and already using `autocomplete="off"`, it is working really good. But just wanted to know about methods without using this.

Comment: Hi Quantamplate. I was having an issue when I closed the browser and then opened it again the values were being stored in the input fields. So when I used the methods above to clear it I noticed that when I opened the browser again and looked really closely I could still see those values just before they got cleared. This is why I was asking about the fastest way to clear them, but using the autocomplete attribute seems to be the fastest solution at the moment.